# Get status from trainer in ML Engine job (Google Cloud Platform)

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform

we have the following architecture to connect with GCP (Google Cloud Platform):

- `Module A`: Launches ML Engine jobs remotely (ex: from AWS, our local machine...)
- `Module B`: GCP (ML Engine). Accepts external requests and runs a specific trainer that we configured.
- `Module C`: Trainer. It is ran by ML Engine. It runs a `learn` process and creates a model under `/export/Servo/<timestamp>`.

So, from what we have seen in the GCP documentation, to override this path we would need to re-implement `estimator.export_savedmodel` which we totally want to avoid.

The other solution that we thought about was to send the output folder from the trainer to the ML Engine job, so that when our `Module A` asks for the status of that ML Engine Job, it gets the output folder.

Is there a way to do this? Is there any easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check this https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/managing-models-jobs in order to view a summary of the ML engine job. Job.state shows if it is in QUEUED, or it has been finished (SUCCEEDED, FAILED, CANCELLED)

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs describe $JOBNAME --summarize
```